# Can't Seem To Fix This Basic Save/Fetch Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Its been like 3 weeks now that I've been seeking help on this site for this simple save/fetch feature using Core Data but I can't get it to work.  I keep getting different suggestions from people and change my code accordingly but can never get it working properly.

Its very discouraging that its taken me this long for this simple error yet I did 100x the work in only the week prior to hit.  Its really a bummer when learning how to program.

**Here is the scenario:**
TableView blank by default until user inputs a name string via the + button in nav bar.  String entered should add a cell to the view with the name as the title.  It should be saved to memory and fetched upon relaunch of application.

**The Problem:**
I get the following error @ line: `cell.textLabel.text = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

in method of: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
2011-04-11 22:40:49.824 Curl[2244:207] -[Routine isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c09ad0
2011-04-11 22:40:50.005 Curl[2244:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Routine isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c09ad0'
```

**My Data Model:**

[image]

**ViewController Code:**

```
`@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize entered;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add an event

-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray insertObject:routine atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [eventsArray addObject:entered];
            [tableView reloadData];
            [self addEvent];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [eventsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Dequeue or create a new cell.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
         NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

this is causing the problem because ....... you are assigning Routine class object as text to textLabel......

```
cell.textLabel.text = [(Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] <thePropertyYouWishToAssign from Routine class>];
```

or
<*********Updated Code**********>

```
Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;
```

<*********Updated Code**********>

in your case.

in alert View delegate .....

```
 if(eventsArray && entered)
    {
//******it will also insert object in coredata.... is it duplicating data?
           Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; tempRoutine.name = entered;
           [eventsArray addObject:tempRoutine];
           [tempRoutine release];
            [tableView reloadData];
             [self addEvent];
     }
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm actually getting an error for that, i think its because of the .name.  It says "No member named "name" in struct_objc_object

Comment: have you declared it as property for name class... if so then use... cell.textLabel.text = [(Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];

Comment: umm, well I just have it declared as a property in the data model.  NSString property called "name".

Comment: Thanks, Ravin!.  Ok so now it works better but there is still a problem.  The property is saving and fetching correctly BUT when I click the add button on the UIAlert Prompt, IT just freezes up and I get a SIGBRT error on the cell.textlabel.text = tempRoutine.name line that says "2011-04-12 00:07:44.558 Curl[2438:207] -[NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59024b0
2011-04-12 00:07:44.561 Curl[2438:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59024b0'"

Comment: But when I restart app, the data is there.

Comment: yes it should..... if we see  [eventsArray addObject:entered];
 line...... now you are entering NSString object in eventsArray in which earlier we have added Routine object..... I want know on which line you have to use properties of Routine.... is it on at first row only...

Comment: umm well the the ui alert just adds a cell to the table. soo whenever the user presses add, it should add the cell to the table, table should be refreshed i think to show this.  but the old data should be there as well that the user entered at a previous time.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the tempRoutine.name = entered line, I get the following error `2011-04-12 00:21:26.796 Curl[2496:207] Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Routine' 
2011-04-12 00:21:26.797 Curl[2496:207] -[Routine setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5948190
2011-04-12 00:21:26.798 Curl[2496:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Routine setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5948190'  It is also happening when I click the add button to add a new cell.

Comment: ok.... Routine is managedObject.... so we can not use it like this... perhaps we should use this.....Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];  tempRoutine.name = entered;

Comment: Hey Ravin, i think it worked on the simulator but when I tried on my iPhone, i got message: `2011-04-12 01:08:06.030 Curl[4171:707] Received memory warning. Level=2
2011-04-12 01:08:23.764 Curl[4171:707] (null)
2011-04-12 01:08:30.622 Curl[4171:707] (null)
2011-04-12 01:08:30.627 Curl[4171:707] -[UITextMagnifierRangedRenderer name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bd6f0
2011-04-12 01:08:30.736 Curl[4171:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextMagnifierRangedRenderer name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bd6f0'`

Comment: Does this have to do with some memory issue or memory leak maybe?  Hmm and for some reason, when I add a cell, it is adding 2 cells instead of 1, both with the same name.

Comment: no this is because of out of scope of routine class object...... and as I wrote we are using Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; to create new Routine object it is making double entry....

Comment: ok thanks, so how do I make sure it only makes a single entry then, not double? I'm posting my  up to date code in the original question.

Comment: Actually if u want to get more points, i made a separate question link for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630738/app-crashing-core-data-problem-or-memory-management thanks