# App Crashing- Core Data Problem Or Memory Management?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, core-data

Console Message:

Had to use picture because wasn't formatting correctly in post as text.

the received memory warning level 2 showed up before the app crashed.

errror comes at this line - `cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;`

link to full-size picture (http://www.box.net/shared/static/7igj3r4trh.png)

[image]

ViewController:

```
@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize entered;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [entered release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add an event

-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray insertObject:routine atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];
    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{


    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];

        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
            tempRoutine.name = entered;
           // Routine *tempRoutine = [[Routine alloc]init];
            //tempRoutine.name = entered;
            [eventsArray addObject:tempRoutine];
            [tempRoutine release];
            [tableView reloadData];
            [self addEvent];
        }
        /*
        if(eventsArray && entered)
        {
            [eventsArray addObject:entered];
            [tableView reloadData];
            [self addEvent];
        }
        */
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [eventsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Dequeue or create a new cell.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Routine *tempRoutine = (Routine *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
         NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hello Faisal, Are you check whats the value come from tempRoutine.name ?

Comment: Sure, ill do a NSLog and check right now.

Comment: Ok, And see whats the value come and let me know.

Comment: I set an NSLog after user clicks the add button, i got `2011-04-12 02:13:14.275 Curl[133:707] tempRoutine.name is: 1977840`.  And app still freezes up after adding a few cells.  Also duplicates cells, etc.

Comment: Hello, Please also check the all objects value on eventsArray. And check what value come of tempRoutine for every index. tempRoutine.name is a int or string?

Comment: If tempRoutine.name is string then you can use cell.textLabel.text = tempRoutine.name; otherwise use cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempRoutine.name];

Comment: I tired using both of those but same issues are present.

Comment: Are you tested all the coming variables value?

Comment: Actually i messed up the NSLog in the comment above, i did %d instead of %@, thats why i got an int, im doing it over now.

Comment: Ok, so so when I NSLog the tempRoutine.name in the method that adds a cell based on user input, the nslog is correct.

Comment: Dear Chetan, I got rid of the duplicate cells when adding new cells by deleting the insert obejct code from addEvent method. However when I relaunch app, it is duplicating all cells. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Hello, Faisal - You can use reloadData method for reload the table.

Comment: would this fix the problem? where would I insert it?  what i am saying is everything is working perfectly until i restart the app after hard exiting it.  then the cells are all duplicated.

Comment: Hello, Add this Method - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 return YES;
}

And 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         // Update the array and table view.
         [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }

     [tableView reloadData];
 }

Comment: all the cells are still duplicating when I hard exit app and relaunch

Comment: the only thing I can think of where it is messing up is the fetch request

Comment: all the cells are still duplicating when I hard exit app and relaunch - try it 3 - 5 time and see what happens. It shows 3 - 5 times duplicate or only ones?

Comment: I tried 4 times just now.  It only duplicated it the first time.  I added a new question here so you can get points for your answer. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631982/core-data-duplicating-tableview-cells-upon-app-launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your Routines, you create them with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`. Then you release them. But `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` doesn't return an object you own according to the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) or the [method's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/insertNewObjectForEntityForName%3ainManagedObjectContext%3a), so you shouldn't be releasing.

Comment: ok so where am i releasing it? and i should remove the releasing code?

Comment: @Faisal: In `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` you should remove the line `[tempRoutine release]`.

Comment: thanks that fixes the crash I think, i just added the most cells ive done usually it crashes after 2.  but the double add is still there.  i noticed it addes one cell to the first position, and the same cell to the last position.  any thoughts?

Comment: I think i got it working, I had duplicate insertobject code in both addevent and dissmiss alert methods

Comment: Ok so I got rid of the duplicate cells when adding new cells by deleting the insert obejct code from `addEvent` method.  However when I relaunch app, it is duplicating all cells.  Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

HI,

IS your table view is showing a lot many data at a time ?

I think this is the only problem with your code. If there are more then 50 to 60 rows you are calling at a time and you are viewing the same by scrolling up and down then it may cause the memory warning.

The best way to use [Lazy loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) , call the number of raws like you can load only 20 raws at a time and then load another rows as user scroll down.

Here is nice [discussion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) on the same. You are not using images still a number of images may cause the crash of application.

Hope this shall solve your issue.

Comment: Actually there are only like 2-3 rows of data in the table. Initially there are 0, until the user adds their own.